# Merging pickled .npz files in a desired format

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have multiple npz files which i want to merge into one npz.file with the format similar to "mnist.npz"

the format of mnist.npz is:

```
((array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
      ...,
      [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],
      [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8),
 array([5, 0, 4, ..., 5, 6, 8], dtype=uint8))
```

Here two arrays are merged into one big npz file.

My two npz arrays are:

x_array:

```
[[[252, 251, 253],
[151, 150, 152],
[ 28,  25,  27],
...,
[ 30,  25,  27],
[ 30,  25,  27],
[ 32,  27,  29]],
[ 23,  18,  20]],

[[ 50,  92, 163],
[ 55,  90, 163],
[ 75, 105, 176],
...,
[148, 197, 242],
[109, 157, 208],
[109, 165, 222]],

[[ 87, 104, 155],
[ 82, 112, 168],
...,
[ 29,  52, 105],
[ 30,  55, 111],
[ 36,  55, 106]]]
```

y_array:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

When i tried to merge my files, the output i got is:

```
(array([[[252, 251, 253],
    [151, 150, 152],
    [ 28,  25,  27],
    ...,
    [ 30,  25,  27],
    [ 30,  25,  27],
    [ 32,  27,  29]],
    [ 23,  18,  20]]], dtype=uint8),  array([[[ 50,  92, 163],
    [ 55,  90, 163],
    [ 75, 105, 176],
    ...,
    [148, 197, 242],
    [109, 157, 208],
    [109, 165, 222]],

    [ 87, 104, 155],
    [ 82, 112, 168],
    ...,
    [ 29,  52, 105],
    [ 30,  55, 111],
    [ 36,  55, 106]]], dtype=uint8),1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

So in the last line, my array is formated as

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

instead of something like:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

My code for merging two npz files is:

```
data = load('x_array.npz',allow_pickle=True)
lst = data.files

for item in lst:        
    x_train = data[item]

#print((x_item,x_train))

data1 = load('y_array.npz',allow_pickle=True)
lst1 = data1.files

for item in lst1:
    y_train = data1[item]

out1 = (*x_train,*y_train)
np.savez('out1.npz',out1)

print(out1)
```

Can anyone please suggest how i can convert my second array of  (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) to array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)? Any suggestions are helpful

Answer (score 0):

After going through my code i found out that by changing the line

```
out1 = (*x_train,*y_train)
```

to

```
out1 = (*x_train,y_train)
```